# How to check if Clojure value supports metadata?

Tags: clojure, metadata

As only symbols and collections support metadata is there a standard way for checking if a value supports metadata? eg.

```
(can-have-metadata? value)
```

At the moment I am checking if the value is an instance of IObj, but curious if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user> (defn meta-available? [x] 
        (instance? clojure.lang.IMeta x))
#'user/meta-available?
user> (meta-available? 1)
;=> false
user> (meta-available? "abc")
;=> false
user> (meta-available? [1 2 3])
;=> true
user> (meta-available? {:a 1})
;=> true
```

Comment: IMeta could be right, but IObj is probably the intended answer: IMeta tells you if a call to `meta` could possibly return non-nil, whereas IObj tells you if a call to `with-meta` will succeed.